# C++ Map not working for me

Tags: c++, dictionary, file-descriptor

I have a problem, i have a `map`  where i want to store data. I add pair to map, but when i try to get it - its like data is not stored. My code:

```
typedef std::map<unsigned long, int> SocketsTableType;
SocketsTableType ClientTable;

inline void AddClient(unsigned long id, int fd)
{
    ClientTable.insert(std::pair<unsigned long, int>(id, fd));
}

inline int GetDescriptorByClient(unsigned long id)
{
    SocketsTableType::const_iterator it;

    for (it = ClientTable.begin(); it != ClientTable.end(); ++it)
    {
        if (it->first == id)
        {
            return it->second;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
 AddClient(223322, 12);
 int fd = GetDescriptorByClient(223322);
 if(fd >= 0)
 {
   // NEVER HERE
 }

}
```

What's wrong with my code?

Thanks!

Comment: Your code is invalid. There is no function `addClient` at all, how did that ever compiled? Or.. did it?

Comment: And it works for me if you replace the call to `addClient` with one to `AddClient`.

Comment: If you make sure `AddClient` or `addClient` is used in both places, the code works fine. But `std::map` has a `find` method which is what you should be using. It is way more efficient.

Comment: sorry, when i paste code here i changed `AddClient` to `addClient`

Comment: No need for the search loop, have a look at the find member function

Comment: nothing with find function too, maybe it's because i trying to access from another thread?

Comment: If you are accessing from another thread you should state that in the question, and explain how you are doing it. The code as posted works as expected (after the typo correction).

Answer (score 2):

You have an error in your code. It won't even compile. There is no function `addClient` declared anywhere. Also, you forgot to include necessary header files. Well, the following program works like a charm:

```
#include <map>
#include <cstdio>

typedef std::map<unsigned long, int> SocketsTableType;

SocketsTableType ClientTable;

inline void AddClient(unsigned long id, int fd)
{
    ClientTable.insert(std::pair<unsigned long, int>(id, fd));
}

inline int GetDescriptorByClient(unsigned long id)
{
    SocketsTableType::const_iterator it;

    for (it = ClientTable.begin(); it != ClientTable.end(); ++it)
    {
        if (it->first == id)
        {
            return it->second;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    AddClient(223322, 12);
    int fd = GetDescriptorByClient(223322);
    if(fd >= 0)
    {
        printf("Found it! FD=%d\n", fd);
    }
}
```